# Calloc'd struct members changing without me doing it - intermittent only

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

I am trying to implement a shunting yard algorithm and then a RPN calculator in C, however I am getting an intermittent fault, which doesn't ever happen when I step through the code line by line! I'm at my wits end!

I have each item stored in a struct, where is_operator is true when the character encountered is a * / - + symbol.

```
struct operator{
    char symbol;
    associativity assoc;
    uint8_t prec;
    float value;
    bool is_operator, is_number;
};
```

This is only ever assigned in line 53 of my code - in the 'assign_operator' function.

```
operator* assign_operator(char symbol, associativity ass, int prec){

    //check the precedence is in limits
    assert(prec <= 6);

    //get memory for the struct
    operator *op= calloc(1, sizeof(op));
    mem_check(op);

    //assign the struct
    op->symbol = symbol;
    op->assoc = ass;
    op->prec = prec;
    op->is_operator = true;
    op->is_number = false;

    return op;
}
```

Show how though it ends up becoming false, I suspect in the print_array function but I have no clue how!

```
void print_array(operator ** array, int size){

    fflush(stdout);

    for (int i = 0; array[i]; i++) {

        if (array[i]->is_number) {
            printf("%f ", array[i]->value);

        }

        else{
            printf("%c ", array[i]->symbol);

        }
    }  

    printf("\n");
}
```

Any finally my shunting yard function which does the 'meat':

```
void infix_rpn(operator** output, const char* equation){

const char symbols[] = { '/', '*', '+', '-' };
unsigned int number_of_operators = num_elems(symbols), q_len = (int)strlen(equation)-1, out_pos = 0;
char input_symbol;
int in_int, i, z = 0;

//get memory for array of operators and set them up
operator **opers = setup_operators(symbols, number_of_operators);

/*
 the FILO 'stack' area, where 0 is the bottom, so the thing to pop is the highest index occupied
 */
operator **stack = calloc(q_len, sizeof(operator));
mem_check(stack);

//iterate through the letter in the equation string
while(equation[z]){

    //test for blank and skip over until it's not blank
    while(isblank(equation[z])){
        z++;
    }

    //is it's a character then set in_int to 0 and put the character in 'input'
    if(!isdigit(equation[z])){
        in_int = 0;
        input_symbol = equation[z++];
    }

    //must be a number entered
    else{
        in_int = atoi(&equation[z++]);
    }

    //if the number is a 0 it must have been a character
    if (!in_int) {

        //loop though the symbols to find a match
        for (i = 0; i < number_of_operators; ++i) {
            if (opers[i]->symbol == input_symbol) {

                int j = 0;
                //find next empy element in queue
                while(stack[j] != NULL && j < q_len){
                    j++;
                }


                /*
                 cant have a + on top of a / so check the precedence
                 a + has a higher precedence than a / therefore
                 if the number is higher, the precedence is less!
                 inverse precedence
                 */
                if (j == 0) {
                    stack[j] = assign_operator(symbols[i], left, i + 3);
                }

                //if the top thing in the queue has a lower precedence than the new operator's
                else {

                    //get the precedence numbers
                    int queue_prec = stack[j - 1]->prec;
                    int new_prec = opers[i]->prec;

                    //if the + is coming down on top of the * they need switching
                    if (queue_prec < new_prec){

                        //pop to output and point to next available element
                        output[out_pos] = stack[j - 1];
                        out_pos += 1;

                        //put new one in the queue in it's place
                        stack[j - 1] = assign_operator(symbols[i], left, new_prec);

                    }

                    //if the things are the same or it's a * on toof a + can just be put on the queue
                    else{
                        //put it on the queue
                        stack[j] = assign_operator(symbols[i], left, new_prec);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //add number to the output queue, then increment the index of the queue
    else{
        output[out_pos] = assign_value(in_int);
        out_pos += 1;
    }


}

//find last thing in the queue
i = 0;
while(stack[i+1]){
    i++;
}

//add the queue to te output stack
while(i >= 0){
    output[out_pos++] = stack[i];
    //needs to be 'popd' here so that the queue no long has any contents
    stack[i--] = NULL;
}

//free_ops(queue, q_len);
free(stack);

free_ops(opers, number_of_operators);
free(opers);

}
```

Any tips as to why this could possibly happen would be appreciated!

Thank you,

Comment: `operator *op= calloc(1, sizeof(op))` - that should be `sizeof *op`. And later in your code, `operator **stack = calloc(q_len, sizeof(operator));` - it is highly likely that should be `sizeof *stack`. Be careful with your sizing specifications when dealing with pointers and the pointed-to size.

Comment: @WhozCraig That sounds like a pretty good basis for an answer, to me... perhaps even working towards mention of valgrind?

Comment: I smell memory corruption. As already mentioned, _"Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), use valgrind. It is master of us all."_ (Apologies to Laplace).

Comment: Thank for the suggestions, made the changes to my `sizeof()`'s and still no change. I also ran Xcode Instruments on it to check for leaks as suggested - there are none!